# How to use multibib in order to insert a second bibliography as a part of an annex?

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing, multibib

I’m currently using `apacite` for my thesis and I would like to use `multibib` in order to have two separate bibliographies. How can I do that ? 
This a MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside=semi,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[numberedbib,nosectionbib]{apacite}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document} 
\backmatter
\section{Conclusion générale}
\bibnewpage 
\nocite{*}
{\raggedright 
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{mabiblio}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you marked the entries for the documentation annex part in a certain way? Or are they all in an extra file?

Comment: I forgot the last part : the annexes. I modified my MWE. The documentation annex is in the same document.

Comment: What i meant was: Did you mark the bibliography entries in a certain way, or are they in an extra bib-file?

Comment: For the moment, I have got just one bib file (\nocite{*}).

Comment: But you need some marker for the entries, that shall be printed in the annex.

Comment: If you add `keyword = {annexentry}` to all the entries, this will be a piece of cake using package `biblatex`.

Comment: Do you mean that I should add to every entry of my bib-file the field keyword = {annex entry} ? Or have I just to put that field somewhere... but where ?

Comment: Sorry, again iwas not clear enough. Add this to all entries, that shall go to the annex. Or move all the entries to another bib file.

Comment: If I create a new bib file, I'll have two bib files. Then, what do I have to do ? Put my new entry into the Annexes section as a chapter and insert the following marks ?
 \bibnewpage  {\raggedright 
\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{mabiblio}}

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=92952#p92952)

Comment: I've just send another MWE waiting for a peer reviewed. But it doesn't work : my annex bib file is not recognized.

Comment: Please edit the question, not the answer.

Comment: Since this is a very simple issue, but obviously needs extensive investigation and explaining, this should be going on at latex-community, where you already stared a thread. I will update the answer below when you are happy with the result.

Comment: Remember, you have to run the example *exactly as posted* without *any* modification.

Comment: First, I did it exactly as it was indicated. But it didn't work and I began to test by myself some ideas...

Comment: I've just moved to latex-community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using package `multibib`:

```
\begin{filecontents}{domiMain.bib}
    @article{cc,
        author= {Crazy Capybara},
        year= {2015},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{domiAnnex.bib}
    @article{bb,
        author= {Busy Bee},
        year= {2015},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{annex}{Annex Stuff}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\begin{document}
\section{usual stuff}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{domiMain}
\appendix
\section{other stuff}
\nociteannex{*}
\bibliographystyleannex{apa}
\bibliographyannex{domiAnnex}
\end{document}
```

This will create a file `annex.aux` that you have to run BibTeX over as well. After both aux files have been processed by BibTeX, run LaTeX twice as usual and you see both bibliographies in your final document.

---

Using package `biblatex`:

```
%\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{cc,
        author= {Crazy Capybara},
        date= {2014},
    }
    @article{bb,
        author= {Busy Bee},
        date= {2015},
        keywords = {appendix}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{usual stuff}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[notkeyword=appendix]
\appendix
\section{other stuff}
\printbibliography[keyword=appendix]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I understand very slowly. I'm not sure that your suggestions suit my needs. If I'm right, the two solutions you propose me imply that I have to use the \cite command in the main body of my text whereas I just need one section including the references I effectively cite and a section with references I don't cite in my text. Is that right ?

Comment: The one you don't cite won't be included in any bibliography. You can add them using `\nocite{*}`, which will simply add *all* to the bibliography. The key is to separate the ones you cited from the ones not cited (which should be included in the annex), meaning either 1) slit the database (multibib) or 2) add a `keywords` field and use package `biblatex`. Either way, you have to change the input in some way or another.